# How do I disable bugsense android?

Tags: android, bugsense

I enable BugSense by default but I'm looking for a simple method to disable BugSense at runtime in case my users don't want bug reports sent.

Hoping for something like the `acra.disable` [preference](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#Enable/disable_ACRA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it is a single line, I am using something like:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if (preferences.getBoolean(PREFERENCE_BUGS, true)) {
    BugSenseHandler.setup(this, myBugsenseKey);
}
```

but this requires an application restart in order to work.

Comment: This does seem to be the accepted way until bugsense add the feature. Thanks